# r: How to change/replace value on random 5% of a factor?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

Lets say that I have

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
  WHO = as.factor(sample(1:3, size = 6000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.80, 0.15, 0.05)))
)
```

Which gives

```
> table(df$WHO)

   1    2    3 
4753  923  324
```

I want to replace the value on random 5% of the `df$WHO == 1`, so these random 5% are allocated to `df$WHO == 2`.

**Expected output**

```
> table(df$WHO)

   1     2    3 
4515  1161  324
```

It is important that the 5% are chosen completely at random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally at random... within `WHO==1`

```
tmp=which(df$WHO==1)
df$WHO[sample(tmp,round(0.05*length(tmp))]=2
```

Comment: Thanks, that technically answered what I asked for. What I see now, is that I need to keep the original `df` and create a new dataframe (eg `df1`) where this 5% random replacement occur. I tried `df1 <- df$WHO[sample(tmp,round(0.05*length(tmp))]=2`, which did not work. Please, can you show me how I can create `df1`, that contains the 5% random replacement, but at the same time keeps the corresponding `df$age` and `df$gender` (which has not been modified)?

Comment: @cmirian age and gender should not have been modified in df anyway. Nevertheless, if you want the new data in a new data frame simply create a copy and do the replacement there, e.g. `df1=df` and then my code, where you substitute df for df1. Or you can create a new column `df$WHO2=df$WHO` and then my code.